# How to identify procedure run by menu item created by add-in

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I use an Excel add-in that was distributed by one of our vendors which pulls information from their site and populates a tab in my worksheet.  The add-in creates a new control button in the right-click menu with several sub-control buttons to select.

What I'm trying to do is determine the procedure that gets called when I right click on a cell and select one of these options, so I can write a macro that will run one of these procedures, among other things.

I'm not trying to change or manipulate anything with the add-in's procedure, just to figure out which procedure I need to call to run one of the functions without having to right click.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will depend how it was done. If you have 2010 or later, it may be done using CustomUI in the file XML (assuming it's an xlam add-in, not a dll or XLL). It could also have been done using CommandBars in VBA, in which case you can loop through the controls on the commandbar and either test the 'OnAction' property or simply try and call its `Execute` method.

Comment: Thank you Rory.  Unfortunately the add-in is a dll.  I've figured out how to loop through the top level menus and display their IDs and names, but not through the right-click commandbar.  I'm not looking for anyone to give me the solution, I'm happy to put the time in myself, but I'd appreciate a little more guidance anyone would be kind enough to provide.

Comment: Which commandbar is it - what are you actually right-clicking?

Comment: Right clicking into certain cells with data.  The add-in recognizes that certain cells have data in them and when I right click these cells there is an option to drill-down into this data set (similar to drilling down into a pivot table, except it queries their servers).  It's this drill-down command I'm trying to figure out how to call directly.

Comment: It might be the `Cell` shortcut menu, or it might be a custom popup menu that the add-in creates. If it's the latter, I think you're out of luck. I take it you can't set a reference to the dll in your VBAProject? (that might show you available methods)

Comment: I'm almost positive it's a custom popup that the add-in creates.  Haven't had any luck referencing the dll but this is outside my knowledge so it's possible I'm off track.  I'm adding it via vbProj.References.AddFromFile "<path/name>" but I'm unable to extract / do anything once I've added it.

Comment: I think you're out of luck if it's a custom popup. Can you manually add it as a reference?

Comment: Thank you Rory, to be honest I'm not sure.  I appreciate your guidance so far . . seems I may have to explore another route.

Comment: Tools - References, browse to the dll and see if you can add it. If you can, open the Obejct Browser and see what is exposed from that dll.